# Why does this for loop return a type 'list'

Tags: python, set, partitioning

I have the following code that generates all of the set partitions of a list/dictionary.

```
#partition gen

def partitions(set_):
    if not set_:
        yield []
        return
    for i in range(2**len(set_)//2):
        parts = [set(), set()]
        for item in set_:
            parts[i&1].add(item)
            i >>= 1
        for b in partitions(parts[1]):
            yield [parts[0]]+b
            
def get_partitions(set_):
    for partition in partitions(set_):
        yield [list(elt) for elt in partition]
```

What I want to know is why, when this for loop is run it returns a type `list` instead of  `string`

```
def brute_force(cows,limit=10):
    total_weight = 0
    for partition in get_partitions(cows):
        for cow in partition:
            print(type(cow))
brute_force(x)
```

When run it returns `<class 'list'>`

Comment: can you give an example of the input (`x`) and the expected output?

Comment: Sure, the input would be a dictionary such as `{'betty':4,'john':7, ... etc}` where names are keys and weights are values. The aim of the program is to iterate through each set partition until the sum of the values in the dictionary is less than or equal to that of the limit, this is to minimize the number of 'trips' needed to 'transport' each 'cow' ie. `for partition in get_partitions([1,2,3]):
    print(partition)` would return ```[[1, 2, 3]]
[[2, 3], [1]]
[[1, 3], [2]]
[[3], [1, 2]]
[[3], [2], [1]]```

Comment: Every yield of your code provides a list (via ``[`` ``]`` list literals). Why would you expect it to provide a string at all?

Answer (score 0):

Method `get_partitions` yields lists

```
def get_partitions(set_):
    for partition in partitions(set_):
        yield [list(elt) for elt in partition] # <-- here
```

So, here `cow` is a list

```
def brute_force(cows,limit=10):
    total_weight = 0
    for partition in get_partitions(cows):
        for cow in partition:  # <-- here
            print(type(cow))
brute_force(x)
```

So, If you want strings, you should convert `cow` to string

```
def brute_force(cows,limit=10):
    total_weight = 0
    for partition in get_partitions(cows):
        for cow in partition:
            string_cow = "".join([str(c) for c in cow])
            print(string_cow)
brute_force({"betty":8,"john": 13, "mark":10})
```